# Is it important that a language is coherent to itself?

Tags: language-design, language-features

I am currently designing a programming language and I'm at the stage of making all the design choices that will guide the developement.

My language has a slightly different syntax and concept to many other languages out here, and I wonder if it's more important that the language blindly follows its concept, or if it's ok to rely on shortcuts and hacks to make it more user-friendly and recognized.

As an example, if a language is meant to be a pure functional one, should it avoid imperative-like statements and the like to be completely coherent to its principles, or is it okay to implement them to make the language maybe easier and / or less boring to use?

Specifically, my language is intended to be a lot extensible (sort of like Lisp's dialects), and I wonder if I should include for loops and the like directly or if I should include them like features added through the extension system to be more coherent, even if this results in strangely looking syntax (something like semicolons at the end of the closing curly brace of blocks).

Comment: What is the goal of your language? Who is it aimed at?

Comment: @svick That's a question I never asked myself. General purpose programming I think (no acadamic research anyway) so maybe it should be aimed to be more user-friendly than coherent. Looking at it's syntax I think it could be also used in shell-based softwares from non programmers (much like Lisp in CAD) so everything points torward the user - friendly side. But will everyday users care about how coherent the language is with its own concept?

Comment: Maybe it's time to step back; if you start implementing some new idea and immediately feel the need to work around it, maybe the idea itself should be improved a bit?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich This isn' t the case. If you were implementing a language where everything is a function, and wanted to add a way to define your own functions, how would you implement it? With a function? Or with a statement that looks like `function name(args) {body}` because this way it's less odd looking and makes the users write less code? It's not a need to work around it, I am just asking what would users prefer and what should be done.

Comment: I know of no language that doesn't get more and more features tacked on as time goes by. And many of them are implemented similarly to how it was done in the language they can from. Familiarity seems to trump concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's be honest - nobody* is going to use your language. You're not going to get it done, or it's not going to work, or it's going to be too slow, or it's not going to be useful, or you're not going to be able to market it, or people are going to look at it and go... "meh, I'll just keep using X".

So is it important to *you* that the language be self-consistent? If you're trying something out, then it's worthwhile to commit to trying that idea out without pollution. If you're just looking to learn, then it probably doesn't matter. If you think I'm wrong, and your language is the next big thing, then serving your customers' needs is important.

And frankly, if you think that you can anticipate all of the design choices and their impact ahead of time, I have a bridge to sell you.

*- *with some statistical error.*

Comment: I am not sure if I want to downvote you because of how rude you sound - or upvote you because of how right you are. I am anyway personally determined to compete it and publish it no matter what. No commonly used language started as big as they are today - look at PHP or Lua - and users will hopefully help develope it. I am going for the 'coherence' way after reading this (because between you and me, it's also easier to implement). And as you said, no one knows how it will change over time.

Comment: @user6245072 - best of luck. I've seen decades of programmers convinced that they weren't like the ones who came before. Occasionally they weren't.

Comment: Thanks so much. Anyway the _fact_ that it won't be used nearly as much as I hope doesn't mean I'll leave the project. After all I can always show it on my curriculum, if needed.

Comment: PHP and Lua both filled open niches when they were introduced.

Answer (score 4):

There are several programming languages that successfully combine functional and imperative paradigms, such as C# and Scala.  Lisp even has a loop macro, and it incorporates Lisp-like syntax (more or less):

```
(loop for x in '(a b c d e)
      do (print x) )

(loop for x from 1 to 5
      for y = (* x 2)
      collect y)
```

Note that Lisp loops are implemented as *macros*, and are not part of the language proper.

There are different dialects of  Lisp.  The lisp loops come from Common Lisp, widely regarded as the practical workhorse of the Lisp family of languages.

Without a loop construct, your users are forced to use *recursion* to implement loops, which can be difficult to reason about.  Functional programming purists would probably say that is a good thing.  Recursive looping pretty much requires that your language be capable of tail recursion, if you expect it to have decent performance.

**Further Reading**
[Loops in Lisp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_loops.htm)